# SSIS SQL char conversion to MS Access Yes/No field

Tags: ssis, char, ms-access-2007

I have an SSIS package I am developing. I am attempting to write data from SQL Server 2005 to MS Access 2007.

I am pretty stumped on how to convert a SQL char(1) field to an Access Yes/No field.

From the information I have gathered, the SQL equivalent of an Access Yes/No field would be a bit field, with values of either 0 or 1.

My SQL char(1) field (which is my source field), contains "N" or "Y". I do not have the option of using a bit field, hence my dilemma. I have tried casting to booleans and integers and haven't had any success.

In my Data flow task, I have tried to create regular expressions to no avail, and derived columns, data transformations, etc to no avail. I am stuck.

I have seen some examples on building conditional statements that loop through the .Row collections. This seems a little overboard, to have to write conditions for NULL checks or string values.

In the MSDN link [SSIS Equivalent to DTS Transform Data Task Properties](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/bf1b703e-dc7c-4e6a-9b8d-c4ed667fd4c8/) ...it has some code somewhat similar to this:

```
If DTSSource("Col010") = "Y" Then
  DTSDestination("X") =  -1
 Else
  DTSDestination("X") =  0
End If
```

Should I be able to manipulate the row values directly, through code? Since the source field is a Yes/No type, does it accept integer values? negative values? Yes is actually "-1" in MS access, and I guess this is confusing me.

It seems that a regular expression would fix this problem but I am unsure how to use that too.

Is there something I am overlooking? There must be a way to convert "CHAR" to "YES/NO".

** I know it is easy to point out here that good ol' 2000 SQL DTS could handle this without any problem, by default, right out of the box, installed by a monkey. I am finding myself spending WAAAAY too much time on the very small quirks of SSIS, such as this Yes/No field problem.

I am unable to find any documentation on the subject of SSIS and MS Access Yes/No fields. MSDN will not allow me to post a question either. I know, poor me :(

Has anyone ever come across this quirk with SSIS and MS Access?

Comment: Access does not have fields, because it is not a database. Jet, on the other hand, is a database, and it does have fields and its own datatypes.

Comment: thanks for the groundbreaking high tech advice. buy yourself a cheeseburger on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See **[this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx)** on MSDN for information about the Derived Column transformation.

It doesn't specifically address what you're trying to do, but some of the examples imply that you should be able to achieve your objective. Set the derived output column's type to DT_BOOL and use a one-line version of the code you have above as the Expression (perhaps with a ternary operator?).

And yes, <strike>Access</strike> Jet represents True as -1. False = 0, and True is Not False. If you apply a bitwise Not to 0, you get the twos complement version of -1.

**Update:** The Jet internal storage of a Boolean **is** as an Integer (go figure--but that's what they chose...). As such, Jet Yes/No fields accept zero (0) for False and non-zero (not just -1) for True. *See Comments*

Comment: You mean *Jet* represents True as -1 and False as 0. Access does not have data types (though VBA does).

Comment: @David W. Fenton: You're right, I'm wrong, everybody hates me, I think I'll go out back & eat worms....

Really, thanks for the clarification--it's *way* too easy to slip into thinking of them as the same, especially when I've been away from them for a while.

Comment: I really dont understand the need to clarify Jet and Access. Can we stick to solving this problem, David? Thanks for pointing out the obvious and thanks for pointing out the un-necessary. Do you know how JET can convert SQL Char types to JET YES/NO fields? Is that better? Do you have an answer?

Comment: Roland, my concern with converting to BOOL, is that -1 and 0 are not BOOLEAN values. Is the Access destination field, (aka the Yes/No field), able to accept BOOLEAN values? I have no clue what to cast this as. I can set it up to return "0" or "-1", that is pretty trivial. But that would make me think a BOOLEAN is not acceptable, but maybe an Integer? If so, there are several Integer types in SSIS and Im not even sure which one is best? Just wondering if anyone has done this before. I mean, successfully. :P

Comment: oooooooooops. sorry. scratch that last comment. Please replace "Access" with "Jet" in the entire previous comment. The Jet police might make an arrest. :P

Comment: The Jet internal storage of a Boolean is as an Integer (go figure--but that's what they chose...). As such, Jet Yes/No fields accept zero (0) for False and non-zero (not just -1) for True.

You can prove this by writing an update or insert query (in the "SQL View" of the Access query editor), that sets the value of a Yes/No field to an integer value. Runs fine, then check the value in a table view.

Comment: what surprises me is that Import/Export Wizard wont even convert this automatically, it produces the same error. I will run through the different casting scenarios and *hopefully* post an answer soon. Thank you for your help. Jet 4 life.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "Access does not have data types" -- sure it does: the hyperlink data type.

Comment: @Devtron: David W. Fenton's world view is stuck firmly in the mid 1990s Jet 3.51 Access95 era. These days, Microsoft refers to both the old Jet engine and the new ACE engine (where 'A' stands for 'Access') collectively as the "Access database engine" e.g. see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA012337221033.aspx you won't find the word 'Jet' on that page there because a) notionally 'Jet' is a deprecated term and b) physically the old Jet engine does not support the new multi-valued data types, only the new ACE does. Plus there is the hyperlink data type which is for the Access UI only.

Comment: The Access database engine's YESNO data type is not Boolean. In common with all SQL data types it is NULLable and exhibits three-value logic. That's not Boolean!

Comment: ...but the twist is, the Access database engine lacks expressions to handle this; instead it uses Boolean logic and incoorectly coerces NULL values to false... sometimes. This inconsistency leads me (and others: see http://allenbrowne.com/NoYesNo.html) to recommend avoiding the YESNO data type. I too would use an INTEGER but with a CHECK constraint on the allowed values.

Comment: @onedaywhen - thank you for the clarification, with actual facts. it really errps me on SO when people do not elaborate, or go into left field. Thank you for clearly providing information, related to the topic. I was originally under the ASSUMPTION that Yes/No fields were boolean, but as you pointed out, they are in fact not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I created a Derived Column.

The regular expression for the column is:

```
[column] == "Y" ? -1 : 0
```

The datatype is:

```
single-byte signed integer [DT_I1]
```

and viola! Jet (aka MS Access, Thanks David W. Fenton!), now displays my Yes/No fields.

After noticing that only one record was appearing in the table, I noticed my test data was invalid and corrected the underlying issue.

This is good documentation on how to cast SQL char(1) fields (with "N" or "Y" values) to MS Access (oooops, I meant Jet) Yes/No fields.

Thank you for everyone's help. Stackoverflow is invaluable.